# Vert.x deployment on aws (best practice)

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm beginner in web development. I used Vert.x framework. And I got app.jar file for the server on aws. Every time I run it with this command:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

But I'm not sure, that is right way (I think it's nonprofessional). Who Can tell, what is best practice?  I heard that, most of apps are deployed on web application containers, such as Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty etc. Please, show me right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a member of the Vert.x core team.*

It is not more professional to deploy a webapp in a container environment than running it directly with an executable JAR.

Actually, the opposite movement can be observed: SpringBoot and Wildfly-Swarm are tools to let you run Spring and JavaEE applications as an executable JAR.

So the real question is: does the tool do the job for you?

Comment: Thanx for reply, I Understand. Can you advice ways (or tool) how to deploy the vertx project on aws server, instead of mine?

Comment: That questions opens to a wide range of answers :-) There are plenty of tools for system configuration and maintenance, application delivery, ...etc.